# Sharepoints 2013: Getting ItemCollection via List.GetItems

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I have the following code, which successfully gets the list, but the spListItems variable never seems to never yield any results, even though the spList reports having listitems.

Any Ideas???

```
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
        ListItemCollection spListItems = null;
        List spList = null;

        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();

                // initilize our collections and vars
                spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("EclipseAppPages");
                clientContext.Load<List>(spList);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // do it again 
                spListItems = spList.GetItems(caml);
                clientContext.Load<ListItemCollection>(spListItems);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // loop items and populate model
                foreach (ListItem l in spListItems)
                {
                    model.Add(l);
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit 18-09: A little bit more info into this, this code is hosted inside a 'autohosted' mvc app for sharepoint. I am accessing the HostWeb from my AppWeb, my first conclusion would be permissions, however the fact that im getting the list back, and interestingly when i debug the variable the spListItems has an item count of > 0 but for some reason the context ISNT lazy loading the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was app permissions, I found the solution to this, trying to find a solution to a query string filter issue.

If you get the same problem, go into your AppParts AppManifest.xml and add the following node:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest   Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web"
         Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Alternatively you can do this via the visual studio wizard, double click your AppManifest file, goto permisions tab, Scope is 'Web', Permission 'Choose relavent permission'.

For more info on app permissions goto http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179892(office.15).aspx

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the result of your query is empty is that there CamlQuery object does not have ViewXml or Query property value.
Read the following article on how to query SharePoint Lists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

Also, Use RowLimit & ViewFields properties to limit the results, for performance considerations.

alternatively you can use Linq to SharePoint if you are comfortable with that.

Comment: ive give this a try and it still doesnt seem to work, I am pretty sure I have run an example that had an empty caml object and that returned results. It maybe my caml query so I will keep playing.

Comment: It is incorrect to assume that the camlQuery cant be empty, it can be empty and will return all results if it is. This answer, is informative in terms of the Caml query, but not relevent to the problem.